# How to execute a task in gradle only after build failed

Tags: gradle, allure

I have folowing code in biuld.gradle:

```
task generateReport(type: Exec){
    onlyIf{
        project.getState().failure
    }
    doLast{
        executable "generateReport.bat"
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test)*.finalizedBy generateReport
```

I've tried before:

```
task generateReport(type: Exec){
    executable "generateReport.bat"
}

tasks.withType(Test)*.finalizedBy generateReport

gradle.afterProject {project, projectState ->
    if (projectState.failure) {
        doLast{
            generateReport
        }
    }
}
```

And others examples, but all was useless..

What I've done incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to use a `BuildListener` as it was mentioned in other answers already. But one more note, you can't call some task the way you did it, with `generateReport`. So you have rather to use an `exec` right in the closure of the listener, as:

```
gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
    if (buildResult.failure) {
        exec {
            executable "generateReport.bat"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your example really help :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to hook into the `buildFinished` lifecycle event, like this:

```
gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
    if (buildResult.failure) {
        println "Build Failed!"
    } else {
        println "Build Succeeded!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually your example don't work for executing task, i've tied it too

Answer (score 0):

`Project.state` is the evaluation state of the project, not some execution state. If you want to do something when the build failed, you should do `gradle.addBuildListener()` and in the `BuildListener` implement the method `buildFinished()` where you can check `result.failure` to see whether the build failed. If you want to perform some action for each failed test tast, you should instead use `gradle.addListener()` and give it an implementation of `TestListener` where you can act on failed tests or test suites. Alternatively you can also add a test listener only to specific test tasks with `testTask.addTestListener()`. Or to have it even nicer, you can do `testTask.afterTest { ... }` or `testTask.afterSuite { ... }`.